Docker container failing to build in GitHub Actions, but it builds on my local machine Ubuntu 24.04
I am trying to build and run a containerized Spring server in a GitHub Actions pipeline. The end goal is to have the backend and frontend both running in the pipeline, so that our Cypress tests can run on push and merge.
The Docker container builds fine on my machine. When I run it in GitHub Actions it fails, the is the end of the logs from the runner:
 #13 [build 4/4] RUN gradle build --no-daemon --stacktrace
#13 0.754 
#13 0.754 Welcome to Gradle 7.6!
#13 0.754 
#13 0.754 Here are the highlights of this release:
#13 0.754  - Added support for Java 19.
#13 0.755  - Introduced `--rerun` flag for individual task rerun.
#13 0.755  - Improved dependency block for test suites to be strongly typed.
#13 0.755  - Added a pluggable system for Java toolchains provisioning.
#13 0.755 
#13 0.756 For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/release-notes.html
#13 0.756 
#13 0.853 To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon.
#13 1.752 Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build 
Error: The operation was canceled.

This is the Dockerfile:
# Use an official Gradle image to build the application
FROM gradle:7.6.0-jdk17 AS build

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the project files to the Docker container
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . .

# Build the application
RUN gradle build --no-daemon --stacktrace

# Use an OpenJDK runtime as a base image
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the JAR file from the build stage to the runtime stage
COPY --from=build /app/build/libs/mynt-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

# Expose the port the application runs on
EXPOSE 8080

# Set the entry point to run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]

These are the steps from the GitHub Actions YAML:
        - name: build container
          run: |
            cd backend
            docker build -t backend .
        - name: run container
          run: |
            cd backend
            docker run -d -p 8080:8080 backend

According to docker images command, the image is 469MB.
